# Sets arguments to Lua interpreters

Tags: lua, luajit, zerobrane

I use actually zerobrane studio and I have compile the last version of luajit ( 2.0.3), and including it in the IDE ( all work fine ) :

```
path.lua = "E:/ZeroBraneStudio-master/luaJit/luajit.exe"
```

I would use some command line options for the luaJit interpreter like ([Luajit command](http://luajit.org/running.html)) :

```
luajit -bl test.lua test.txt
```

or

```
-jon / -joff
```

but when I added it in system configuration :

```
arg.lua = "-b test.lua test.out"
```

Nothing happens. I see the arguments  on output console but not anymore.

What is the procedure in ZeroBrane IDE with an independant luajit compiled to pass parameters compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ZeroBrane Studio doesn't have a way to provide interpreter options (as of version 1.10). As a workaround, you can create a batch file that calls luajit with the requires parameters and specify that batch file in `path.lua` configuration setting.